# What's the order in applying SMOTE transformation in a pipeline?

Tags: python, predictive-modeling, logistic-regression, sampling, smote

Here's the thing, I have an imbalanced data and I was thinking about using SMOTE transformation. However, when doing that using a sklearn pipeline, I get an error because of missing values.

This is my code:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

# SELECAO DE VARIAVEIS
categorical_features = [
    "MARRIED",
    "RACE"
]

continuous_features = [
    "AGE",
    "SALARY"
]

features = [
    "MARRIED",
    "RACE",
    "AGE",
    "SALARY"
]


# PIPELINE
continuous_transformer = Pipeline(
    steps=[
        ("imputer", SimpleImputer(strategy="most_frequent")),
        ("scaler", StandardScaler()),
    ]
)

categorical_transformer = Pipeline(
    steps=[
        ("imputer", SimpleImputer(strategy="median")),
        ("onehot", OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown="ignore")),
    ]
)

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ("num", continuous_transformer, continuous_features),
        ("cat", categorical_transformer, categorical_features),
    ]
)

pipeline = Pipeline(
    steps=[("preprocessor", preprocessor), ("classifier", LogisticRegression())]
)

X = df[features]
y = df[['binary_response']]


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    X, y, train_size=0.8, random_state=42
)

X_train_smote, y_train_smote = oversample.fit_resample(X_train, y_train)

pipeline.fit(X_train_smote, y_train_smote)
```

That doesn't work because I have missing data. But I'm not sure what to do because of the pipeline and the order I should use.

Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Hi, I believe you need to fill in your missing values before trying to apply SMOTE. Can you try and impute the missing data first? As an example, you could use: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer.html

Comment: You might find my post [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/578545/247274) to be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Resampling should happen after preprocessing but before the classifier.

It is best to use imblearn's Pipeline, instead of scikit-learn's Pipeline. Imblearn's Pipeline is designed to work with resampling.

```py
from imblearn.pipeline import Pipeline
```